# When a condition is met -> convert public variable to private

Tags: kotlin, conditional-statements, private, public

I am new to Kotlin and I was wondering if there is a way to make a variable that is originally public - to private, if a certain condition is met. And if the condition is met and the variable is private skip  certain part of the program - something like the "go to" option in C.

For example:

var a = 10
var b = 20

if a == 10 -> make b private

go to fun something()

else -> b stays public

->continue the normal flow of the program

Comment: This sounds *extremely* like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info). Why do you want to do this? What is your ultimate goal?

Comment: https://github.com/LyuboslavStoimenov/Kotlin
This is the code, the problem is when i input an exitTime earlier than entryTime, it messes up the fun shortestParkingDuration() and fun averageParkingDuration(), and i want to fix it by making exitTime private in some way but i can't come up with a working idea.

Comment: public/private visibility affects the code the compiler allows you to write. You can't modify it at runtime and have it affect what happens when something is called. Use traditional constructs such as if/else and Booleans to create your proper logic for runtime behavior.